# How can i fetch activities using date range from fitbit?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to fetching activities from Fitbit but getting date range error. 

How can i resolve it? 

My URL is `https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/date/2016-08-08/2016-08-09.json`

Fitbit Response:

```
{ errors:    [ { errorType: 'validation',
       fieldName: 'resource path',
       message: 'Invalid time series resource path: /activities' } ] }
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed URL prams -> https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/date/2016-08-08/2016-08-09.json

Correct url-> https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/steps/date/2016-08-08/2016-08-09.json